# dropdown initializing input type="text" on postback

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, postback

I have several text boxes `<input type="text">` as well a a dropdownlist`<asp:DropDownList>`
I prefer to use this asp control as I want to bind it with data. The thing is every time I make a selection the text boxes re-initializes due to post back.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpPleaseSelect" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpPleaseSelect_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" >
                    <asp:ListItem>[Please Select Yes Or No]</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtLastName" onkeyup="checkTextBoxes()" onfocus="checkTextBoxes()" />

protected void drpPleaseSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var valueDropdown = drpPleaseSelect.SelectedValue.ToString();
    if (valueDropdown == "[Please Select Yes Or No]")
    {
        labChkDropDown.InnerHtml = "Please select yes Or no";
    }
    else if (valueDropdown == "Yes" || valueDropdown == "No")
    {
        //bind a different asp:dropdownlist with database data
    }
}
```

Is there a way for my html text boxes not to be affected by postback as I make changes the index of the dropdown list?

Comment: 1.instead of calling onselectedindex change you can call a javascript function to that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that every time you make a selection that the text boxes re-initialize, are you setting them on PageLoad or a function that is called from PageLoad?

If that is the case I think you are missing a check for IsPostback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    //Do stuff that you only want done on the inital page load.
    //Like setting up inital values in textboxes, etc.
  }
}
```